# shortening headers using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have headers like

```
>XX|6226515|new|xx_000000.1| XXXXXXX
```

in a text file which I am trying shorten to

```
>XX6226515
```

using `awk`. I tried

```
awk -F"|" '/>/{$0=">"$1}1' input.txt > output.txt
```

but it yields the following instead

```
>XX|6226515|new|
```

Comment: Either your awk is broken or your input file is corrupt. The only other possible explanation for there only being one `>` before `XX` and `|6225615|new|` in your output given that input file and that command line, is that the input, output and/or script you posted are not what you really have.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1$2}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Output:

```
>XX6226515
```

Answer (score 3):

sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/|//' -e 's/|.*//'
```

The first substitution removes the first vertical bar, the second one removes the second one and anything after it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'|' '$0=$1$2' <<< ">XX|6226515|new|xx_000000.1| XXXXXXX"
>XX6226515
```

Comment: some explanation of your answer may help :)

Comment: @Chimoo This is just the same as `{print $1$2}`. You do set the new line equal to `$1$2`, and since its a true test, it does the default action, `print $0`

Comment: It is baffling that this answer was **critically** reviewed where as other answer on this question was not. This answer correctly modifies OP's attempt at re-constructing the `$0` hence has my up-vote.

Comment: This answer had been flagged, so I just asked for more info, that's all

Comment: The lack of explanation doesn't justify flagging an answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

This `cut` can also make it:

```
cut -d"|" --output-delimiter="" -f-2
```

See output:

```
$ echo ">XX|6226515|new|xx_000000.1| XXXXXXX" | cut -d"|" --output-delimiter="" -f-2
>XX6226515
```

- `-d"|"` sets `|` as field delimiter.
- `--output-delimiter=""` indicates that the output delimiter has to be empty.
- `-f-2` indicates that it has to print all records up to the 2nd (inclusive).

---

Also with just `bash`:

```
while IFS="|" read a b _
do
  echo "$a$b"
done <<< ">XX|6226515|new|xx_000000.1| XXXXXXX"
```

See output:

```
$ while IFS="|" read a b _; do echo "$a$b"; done <<< ">XX|6226515|new|xx_000000.1| XXXXXXX"
>XX6226515
```